# How can I insert/update a List<T> as member of an entity in SQLite?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, collections, litedb

Let's say I have a really simple class:

```
public class myClass{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public object SomeProperty {get;set;}
    public List<string> ListOfStrings {get;set;}
}
```

whenever I try to retrieve `myClass` entity from the database, `ListOfStrings` will be empty even though I have accurately debugged into the CRU<s>D</s> process to make sure that `ListOfStrings` is well populated before `Insert()` or `Update()` method is called on the entity

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? You need to should the methods you use for adding to and reading from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entity you're saving in the collection should have an ID property and you should link the two entities using foreign keys. If you're using entity framework, you could define your classes like this:

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public int SomeEntityID {get;set;}
    public string Message {get;set;}
    public MyClassID {get;set;}
}

public class MyClass
{
    public int MyClassID {get;set;}
    public object SomeProperty {get;set;}
    public List<SomeEntity> ListOfSomeEntity {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can retrieve your entity like this:

```
var myClass = context.MyClass.Include(c=>c.ListOfSomeEntity)
              .Single(c=>c.MyClassID == 1);
```